# Which "building block" to use? Gridview, listview etc?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gridview

I'm wondering which building block to use at the moment. I'm trying to create an activity, which will have this "box" at the bottom of the activity, that can be scrolled horizontally. When an item of the box is in the middle position (ex. 12pm), that one's values will be displayed on top.

Should I go with grid view or should I start from scratch to build this? Hopefully the url of an image below will explain it a bit more.

http://s14.postimg.org/nnn4b6fo1/example.png

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with HorizontalListView, please go through the link

1) https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView

2) http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2012/11/horizontal-listview-in-android-example.html

Hope this help..

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` with page's width set to `1/n` (with n = number of elements you want to be displayed).

Put an `OnPageChangeListener` on it to listen for page changes.

When the page changes update the UI on the upper part of the screen.